# Transferring Data Back to Original View

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, data-transfer

So I am able to transfer the data from the first view to the second view like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Check Mark Segue"])
      {
        NSLog(@"Transfering Data");
        AutoRenewDrop *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.transferData = self.renewDate.text;
      }
}
```

However, I try to transfer a new value back to renewDate.text when the user hits done and the transferData is working correctly but the renewDate.text does not change. Here is the code that I am using to transfer the data back:

```
-(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
AddR *add = [[AddR alloc] init];
add.renewDate.text = transferData;

}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? `- [[SomeClass alloc] init]` returns a new instance every time it's called, so this would set the property of *another instance of the AddR class...* You should distinguish between classes and objects.

Comment: I understand, Thanks for commenting. So would I just do AddR *add;? Sorry, I'm not that new to Xcode but this is the first time I've had to work with sharing data between views so I am still learning the ropes.

Comment: **Don't do that!** It either will be uninitialized (and crash) in that case, or will be nil, then it won't do anything. You need to add a property to the second view, set it to the first view (thus essentially pass along the first view itself), and from the 2nd view, use that property on `self` (which points to the 1st view) to set the text.

Comment: Ah, of course. Care to give me an example of how this works if you don't mind? I am trying to understand how to do this. And I changed it to I believe the way you were talking about and it is still not working for me.

Comment: on the class of the second view, declare `@property UIView *previousView;`, then from the same class, write `[self.previousView setText:blah];`. Also don't forget to write `secondView.previousView = self;` from the method of the class of the first view where you create the second view instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a property that contain a reference of the first view into the second view :

```
@interface AutoRenewDrop
@property(weak, nonatomic) AddR *callerView;
@end
```

And then in the done method of the second view you can just update the variale in the caller view :

```
-(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
callerView.renewDate.text = transferData;
}
```

Of course when you instantiate the second view you will have to set the reference, in this way :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Check Mark Segue"])
      {
        NSLog(@"Transfering Data");
        AutoRenewDrop *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.transferData = self.renewDate.text;
        controller.callerView = self; //Here, you are passing the reference to this View
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much works like a charm. Only thing is I need to edit one thing with your answer! @aleroot

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate.
You can read a pretty good tutorial about protocols and delegates [here](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/).

Lets say you have 2 ViewControllers - VC1 and VC2, and lets say that VC1 displays VC2.

In VC2.h

```
@protocol VC2Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)updateData:(id)theData;
@end

@interface
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<VC2Delegate> delegate;
@end
```

In VC2.m

```
@syntesize delegate;

- (void)done
{
    [delegate updateData:myData];
}
```

In VC1.h

```
@interface VC1 : UIViewController<VC2Delegate>
```

In VC1.m

```
- (void)goToVC2
{
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    vc2.delegate = self;
    // present vc2
}

- (void)updateData:(id)data
{
    // update what you need
}
```